# How do I do a column-wise subtraction using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have:

```
array([[ 5,  4,  3,  3],
       [ 5,  4,  3,  3],
       [ 5,  4,  3,  3],
       [ 5,  4,  3,  3],
       [ 5,  4,  3,  3]])
```

And then I have

`array([1, 2, 3, 4])`

I want to subtract each column in the original matrix with the corresponding column value in the 1d array.

So, I want it to become

```
array([[ 4,  2,  0,  -1],
       [ 4,  2,  0,  -1],
       [ 4,  2,  0,  -1],
       [ 4,  2,  0,  -1],
       [ 4,  2,  0,  -1]])
```

How can this be achieved in numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier than you think:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: arr = np.array([[ 5,  4,  3,  3],
    ...:                [ 5,  4,  3,  3],
    ...:                [ 5,  4,  3,  3],
    ...:                [ 5,  4,  3,  3],
    ...:                [ 5,  4,  3,  3]])

In [3]: sub = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [4]: arr - sub
Out[4]:
array([[ 4,  2,  0, -1],
       [ 4,  2,  0, -1],
       [ 4,  2,  0, -1],
       [ 4,  2,  0, -1],
       [ 4,  2,  0, -1]])
```

NumPy broadcasts automatically, so just use the `-` operator!

Comment: Wow, this is great! Thanks